# Graph API with ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly

I would like to get information from Microsoft graph web API. I followed these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The problem is that the variable "token" in the AuthenticateRequestAsync method is always null. It means that the Blazor app does not get the token.

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
                    new AccessTokenRequestOptions()
                    {
                        Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" }
                    });
    
                if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization ??= new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                        "Bearer", token.Value);
                }
            }
```

The Program.cs has the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>(options =>
             {
                 options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
                 builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                 
             });

            builder.Services.AddGraphClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
```

In Index.razor I just add two lines of code I OnInitializedAsync method

```
var request = GraphClient.Me.Request();
user = await request.GetAsync();
```

I spent a lot of time to figure out what is the main issue but without success. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: How is your "AzureAD" configuration like?

Comment: Here is my Azure Ad:
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yyy",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }

It is worth mentioning if I apply the authentication based on user intervention everything works fine. Due to this fact, I think that the AzureAd configuration is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi Samo, any updates?

Comment: Allen Wu thanks for your help. I followed the instructions step-by-step in your link but the problem is not solved. I published my project at the following link: https://github.com/Senso4sLab/BlazorMSGraph. Is it possible that you try with your settings? Thanks for your help in advance. Sorry that I did not reply immediately but I am working on three different projects and sometimes is so hard switching between them very quickly:)

Comment: I notice that you remove the "log in" part. Why? If you don't sign in, the access token is null as expected. But I can hardly modify your code to make it work. All you need to configure is following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and then [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (Until **Call Graph API from a component using the Graph SDK** part).

Comment: I have uploaded a sample code [here](https://github.com/hg3317593-1/BlazorSample) for your reference. Remember to modify the `appsettings.json` file and access `https://localhost:44318/GraphExample` to see if how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to apologize if I did not mention that I need registration without user intervention. I would like that when the user clicks the button and the system automatically registers to my account and send an email to me. This will be used for our webpage.

Comment: Do you mean you want users to submit a registration request to you, and then you will create an AAD user for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please imagine the single-page website. Usually, this kind of page has a "contact us" tab where is the contact form. If the user fills up the contact form then data have to be somehow sent to us. For this purpose, I tried to use MS graph API. When the user clicks the submit button, in the background the registration to my account will be created and an email will be sent to me. It means that the user is not aware of any registration procedure. – Samo Simoncic

For your app to be able to create users in a tenant, it needs to use an app only flow which requires a secret. We do not advise exposing app only flows of this nature, which can easily be exploited to create bogus users or overwhelm your tenant, open to the general public.

The best approach would be to take this registrations in a local DB, and then have a daemon app process them behind the scenes. Here is the sample where [daemon console application is calling Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cause of the issue.

But I can make it work with the following code and configuration:

**Program.cs**

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        // Adds the Microsoft graph client (Graph SDK) support for this app. 
        builder.Services.AddMicrosoftGraphClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");

        // Integrates authentication with the MSAL library
        builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
        });
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/exxxxx4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2xxxxxb",
    "ClientId": "7xxxxxx8-88b3-4c02-a2f8-0a890xxxxxx5",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ValidateAuthority": "true",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can refer to the configuration and sample code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph).

Answer (score 0):

I have cloned your repo from the GitHub URL you posted in the comments.
There is no issue with the code to fetch the data from the Microsoft Graph API, the problem is that you have written the code of calling the API when the apps shows the index component before even the user logs in, you have to check if the user is logged in first and add a login button to the UI or you can add [Authorize] to the index page so it will redirect the user to Login before it shows the component and make the API and to implement that make sure to add the CascadingAuthenticationState and AuthorizeView to your App.razor as following

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="/authentication/login">Login with Microsoft</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And then in your Index.razor add at the top the following line

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

Then you launch the app if the user is not logged in, he/she will be asked to do so and then go to the Index component and make the API call which will succed then

Comment: I completely understand your modifications but I would like that the registration is made automatically without user intervention. I would like to use this approach for our webpage. When the user fills in the contact form the email will be sent.

Comment: You mean, you want the user to be redirected automatically to the login page without the need to click Login?

Comment: Please imagine the single-page website. Usually, this kind of page has a "contact us" tab where is the contact form.  If the user fills up the contact form then data have to be somehow sent to us. For this purpose, I tried to use MS graph API. When the user clicks the submit button, in the background the registration to my account will be created and an email will be sent to me. It means that the user is not aware of any registration procedure.